# regarding Oracle PL SQL Loop

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, database-sequence

Doing some coding today. Encountered following problem with sequences.
This code in PL/SQL:

[image: Click to see code]

does not work as expected i.e. sequence is not incremented by 10 as I wanted - only by 1. This code:

[image: Click to see code]

works fine. Sequence is incremented by 10 as expected.

Why is this explain?

Comment: [Please post formatted text, not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: I think you do not need to type this code and look.. i hope conceptual answer here.. because, in those images i did not provide the full code also.. i just need to know why this kind of thing happen

Comment: Why did you replace your code with images?

Answer (score 3):

You can see what's happening by adding some debugs:

```
create sequence s42;

set serveroutput on

declare
  cursor c is
    select s42.nextval from dual;
  n pls_integer;
begin
  open c;
  for i in 1..5 loop
    fetch c into n;
    dbms_output.put_line('i: ' || i
      || '; n: ' || n
      || '; found: ' || case when c%found then 'true' else 'false' end);
  end loop;
  close c;
end;
/

i: 1; n: 1; found: true
i: 2; n: 1; found: false
i: 3; n: 1; found: false
i: 4; n: 1; found: false
i: 5; n: 1; found: false


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You are only opening the cursor once, and the cursor only returns one row. So, the first fetch finds a value (`c%found` is true). The second and subsequent fetches do not find a row because the single-row result set has already been exhausted.

In short, the `nextval` is only executed once, so the sequence is only incremented once.

In your second version the entire query is re-executed inside the loop, so `nextval` is called multiple times, and the sequence is thus incremeneted multiple times too.

You'd see the same if you re-opened the cursor inside the loop:

```
declare
  cursor c is
    select s42.nextval from dual;
  n pls_integer;
begin
  for i in 1..5 loop
    open c;
    fetch c into n;
    dbms_output.put_line('i: ' || i
      || '; n: ' || n
      || '; found: ' || case when c%found then 'true' else 'false' end);
    close c;
  end loop;  
end;
/

i: 1; n: 2; found: true
i: 2; n: 3; found: true
i: 3; n: 4; found: true
i: 4; n: 5; found: true
i: 5; n: 6; found: true
```

but that's really just a longer, more complicated way of doing a `select ... into`, since it can only return one row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Only in the second code is executing nextval 10 times  because NEXTVAL is called **inside a loop**

The [NEXTVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm) is causing the increment

> NEXTVAL: Increments the sequence and returns the next value

The first code call nextval once and store value in cursor, Then same value is updating 10 times in loop